# How to get the destination nid from an URL object

Tags: 8, uri

In a preprocess function I want to access the destination node id via the [URL object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x)

I cannot find any method that will return the node id for me but I can clearly see that it holds the node id. (see attached)

[image]

Any idea how I can get the node id without going the long way of generating it from the URL path?

Comment: $your_url_object->getRouteParameters() should do it I think from memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using the latest Devel, 4.0.1, which sadly currently doesn't show the [available methods tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjXKq.png) unless you [patch it](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/politsin/snipets/master/kint.patch).

If you had the available methods tab, you would've seen that you can retrieve using the public method [getRouteParameters](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AgetRouteParameters/8.2.x)

```
$nid = $url_object->getRouteParameters()['node'];
```

Comment: hey thanks, that worked although just `['node']` at the end did the job just fine,

Comment: Also thanks for the patch, do you know why this has been removed in the newest version? It is pretty handy.